# Where do we declare attributes of a rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I come from a Java background and I have started learning Ruby on Rails. Consider the following code mentioned in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The guide mentions that this creates a model Product mapped to a table products (using the pluralized mechanism of ruby). It also mentions, 'By doing this you'll also have the ability to map the columns of each row in that table with the attributes of the instances of your model.'

But we did not declare any attributes inside the model Product. How does it know what are its attributes?

One assumption: Every attribute of table is made as an attribute of model. Is it true? Then, do we create the SQL table first? If I change the table later on (adding new columns, say) does it also change my model dynamically?

Comment: All of your assumptions are correct. Keep reading the guide.

Comment: This is the beauty of rails and one of the challenges when you are first learning to use it.  There's so much "magic" that happens under the hood that it can be disconcerting at first.  Yes, the attributes are "automatic" and if you change the table later, those too will be automatically added.  You *will* need to come back and adjust the security permissions in the models/controllers (what's accessible) but they are all there automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important distinction is that we're talking about **ActiveRecord** models, i. e. subclasses (direct and indirect) of `ActiveRecord::Base`, those that use its persistence mechanism. **The following is not true for Rails models in general**. But then again, for non-AR models the question makes no sense :)

> Every attribute of table is made as an attribute of model. Is it true?

**Yes.**

> Then, do we create the SQL table first?

**Exactly.** `rails g model` creates a **model file** and a **migration** that contains a declaration for a table behind the model. So before using your model, you have to run the migration first.

> If I change the table later on (adding new columns, say) does it also change my model dynamically?

Now that's tricky. It's most certainly true if the application is reloaded after the changes (e. g. in development mode this happens every now and then), since the model class will be reconstructed. So the answer is **yes, most of the time**.

This is, however, only about the *internal structures* of the model class (visible in e. g. `Model.columns`) you don't always have to care about. When fetching data, **all the columns of the result set** will be mapped to attributes of the model objects. So this keeps even custom columns you specify in `SELECT`s:

```
Thing.select(:id, "1 AS one").first.attributes
#> SELECT  "things"."id", 1 AS one FROM "things"  ORDER BY "things"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
# => {"id"=>1, "one"=>1}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :-).. Just to clarify, when we do `rails g model <ModelName> <Attribute>:<Type>` rails create a rb file inside db/migrate that has create_table statement and our model refers to this statement, right? Also, what do you mean by the term 'migration'? It is related to tables in database but I don't get a clear definition.

Comment: @whitehat No, AR model only refers to an actual database table; migrations are just one way of changing it (a recommended one). That file inside `db/migrate` is an ActiveRecord migration that describes an incremental change to the database structure, more on that in the guides.

Answer (score 5):

It works like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
```

*`Product`* is subclassed to *`ActiveRecord::Base`* (you know subclassing from Java, right?).

`ActiveRecord::Base` can be seen [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb):

> Active Record objects don't specify their attributes directly, but rather infer them from
>     # the table definition with which they're linked. Adding, removing, and changing attributes
>     # and their type is done directly in the database. Any change is instantly reflected in the
>     # Active Record objects. The mapping that binds a given Active Record class to a certain
>     # database table will happen automatically in most common cases, but can be overwritten for the uncommon ones.

You can read through the other code; in short, it means that *ActiveRecord* uses the SQL schema to populate the respective attributes.

--

Because your `model` is a `Class`, `ActiveRecord` will basically create a series of [`setter/getter` instance methods](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/110-instance-variables) with the values from your db.

When you invoke said class, `ActiveRecord::Base` will populate the respective instance methods with the values in your db, allowing you to call `@product.name` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-).. That helped.

Answer (score 1):

Models in rails are just an easy way of binding the data from the database. Model *is* the data.

A model **represents** a table and will have all the columns of that table as its attributes.

The model in point is `Product`. By rails conventions, this model is directly mapped to `products` table in the database and will have all the attributes that the table has as its columns.

Models and tables are interlinked and models serve as an easy abstract layer over the actual data to provide ease of work and additional validations and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to declare specific attributes in a migration (which creates the tables).  Otherwise, ActiveRecord makes a some key assumptions:

```
name of the table = lowercase version of class name = products
primary key = id
```

Then it can use raw SQL when it starts the connection to get a list of attributes from the table:

```
DESCRIBE table products;
```

This gives it a full listing of the fields in the table.  It sets up attributes in each instance of the class based on these fields.