# How to select only part of json, stored in Postgres, with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

Say I have a model `User`, which has a field of type `json` called `settings`. Let's assume that this field looks roughly like this:

```
{
  color: 'red', 
  language: 'English', 
  subitems: 
    {
      item1: true, 
      item2: 43, 
      item3: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    }
}
```

If I do `User.select(:settings)` I will get all the settings for each user. But I want to get only the languages for a user. I tried both:

```
User.select("settings -> 'language'")
```

and

```
User.select("settings ->> 'language'")
```

but this just returns empty objects:

```
[#<User:0x007f381fa92208 id: nil>,
...]
```

Is this at all possible? If yes - can I do it using just `json` or do I need to switch to `jsonb`?

Comment: *empty objects* -- sure of that? Try doing `.map(&:attributes)` on the result.

Comment: You are right. `attributes` returns this `{"id"=>nil, "?column?"=>"English"}`. What confused me is the fact that normally the object would look like this when selecting a normal (not json) attribute: `#<User:0x007f38200f3598 id: nil, name: "John">`. However, apparently json selected data doesn't work like that.

Comment: It's just `#to_s` that's defined in a way that only outputs **known** columns. **Custom** columns from `select` are not known to be inside the table, so they're not printed out in `#to_s`, but are [mapped regardless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701667/where-do-we-declare-attributes-of-a-rails-model/34705079#34705079).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `User.select("settings -> 'language' as user_language")`.
Each object in the resulting relation should respond to `user_language`.

Comment: Cheers! Happy to help. BTW - it seems that without naming the selected value with a `as user_language` the result will still include the value but under a weird `?column?` key.

Comment: Do you mind also taking a look at this question [How to exclude parts of json when selecting, stored in Postgres, using ActiveRecord?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314920/how-to-exclude-parts-of-json-when-selecting-stored-in-postgres-using-activerec)

Comment: Yes, I also saw the `?column?` key.

Comment: in rails 6.1.3:

`column->'field'` lead to the error `Mysql2::Error: Invalid JSON path expression`

`column->'$.field'` allowed me to get the property