# How to exclude parts of json, stored in Postgres, when selecting using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

This is a follow up question to this one:

[How to select only part of json, stored in Postgres, with ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313997/how-to-select-only-part-of-json-stored-in-postgres-with-activerecord/35314425#35314425)

Say I have a model `User`, which has a field of type `json` called `settings`. Let's assume that this field looks roughly like this:

```
{
  color: 'red', 
  language: 'English', 
  subitems: 
    {
      item1: true, 
      item2: 43, 
      item3: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    }
}
```

The difference to the question cited above is that I'd like to know how to exclude part of the json. So here, I want to select everything from `settings` except:

```
subitems: 
  {
    item1: true, 
    item2: 43, 
    item3: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  }
```

Comment: Much more complex than the related question :] Would a solution using two queries suite you? First query to get all top level json keys, second query to actually select all fields expect for the ones you wish to exclude.

Comment: Well, actually, I wouldn't mind just selecting all the keys, that I need manually. So I would need something like: `User.select("settings -> ['color', 'language'] AS modified_settings")`, which should return objects, that respond to the method `modified_settings`, which should return `{color: 'red', language: 'English'}`. Do you know how to select multiple keys at once?

Comment: Unfortunately I could find a way to retrieve multiple keys at once either. But you can always construct you query dynamically with something like `keys_to_fetch.map{ |k| "setting -> '#{k}' as setting_#{k}"}.join(',')`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think this is a good workaround!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my case, 
`>>User.select("subitem -> 'item1' AS subitem1", "subitem->'item2' AS subitem2").map(&:attributes)`

with *rails 5*